# Competitive programming: "Time exceeded error"

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Problem description:

> **Task A. Amount of subtractions**
>
> You have an array ***a*** length ***n***. There are m queries
>   (***l<sub>i</sub>,r<sub>i</sub>***), for each of which it is necessary
>   to find the sum of numbers sub-array
>   [***l<sub>i</sub>,r<sub>i</sub>***]
>
> **Input data format:**
>
> The first line contains two integers ***n*** and ***m (1 ⩽ n, m ⩽
>   10<sup>5</sup>)*** - the number of numbers and queries. The second
>   line contains ***n*** integers ***a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>,. . . ,
>   a<sub>n</sub> (1 ⩽ a<sub>i</sub> ⩽ 10<sup>9</sup>)*** - the numbers of
>   the array. Each of the following m lines contains two integer numbers
>   ***l<sub>i</sub>*** and ***r<sub>i</sub>*** ***(1 ⩽ l<sub>i</sub> ⩽ r<sub>i</sub> ⩽ n)*** - the query.
>
> **Output data format:**
>
> For each request, take a separate line to answer it.

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long n = 0;
    long m = 0;

    long l = 0;
    long r = 0;

    register long t = 0; // temporary variable, that contains intermediate results

    scanf("%ld%ld", &n, &m);

    long  a[n];
    long  tr[m]; // array, that contains results

    for (register long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%ld", &a[i]);

    for (register long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%ld%ld", &l, &r);

        l--;
        r--;

        t = 0;
        if (l != r) {
            for (register long j = l; j <= r; j++)
                t += *(a + j);
        } else t = *(a + l);

        tr[i] = t; 
    }
    for (register long i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%ld\n", tr[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

My solution is passing only 6 tests out of 11. Other 5 always return

> Time exceeded error

I am really new to competitive programming. **How should i optimize my code to get big-O complexity less than O(n<sup>2</sup>)?** **Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: *I am really new to competitive programming.* -- `long  a[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  The number of entries in an array in C++ is denoted by a compile-time constant, not a variable.  "Competitive programming" doesn't teach you how to write programs, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, ,It is not C++. The program is written in C and compiled  with GCC.There are no warning or errors.

Comment: You had C++ tags previously.  In any event, your solution is `O(n^2)`.  You have a nested loop -- imagine if `m` is very large.  That may be the cause of the timeout.  Any solution that uses nested loops is usually not going to pass these tests, as these tests are supposedly designed to make you write "simple", but naive solutions that are too slow.  You have to devise a solution whose big-O complexity is less than `n^2`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I removed c++ tag, because it seemed unrelated. you can use that expression (both in C and C++) and it works in gcc or clang. But I think it is a feature of gcc compiler and it is illegal by standard.

Comment: @Afshin, no it is not a feature of compiler, arrays with variable number of entries behave as VLA.

Comment: @StanislavK A lot of compilers does not support it(for example msvc). standard says size should be constant.

Comment: @StanislavK For C++ you cannot use VLA's, as they are not part of the standard.   If you're compiling as C++ code (even though on the surface, the code is `C`), the program you posted uses non-C++ syntax.  If you're compiling using a true `C` compiler, then that's a different story.  Also the `register` keyword doesn't really do anything these days, given how good compilers are at optimizing code.  If you're thinking that using tricks like `register` will help, I don't think so.  Your solution requires a rethinking -- back to pencil and paper to work this out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you very much for help. I'll try to come up with a new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the cumulative sum of the array and store it in another one, that is to say,
`accumulated[i]` = sum of numbers of the array up to ith index. This can be computed in O(n).

Then for a query, the answer will be `accumulated[r] - accumulated[l]`. This is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem can be solved in O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

You can use the prefix sum method to reduce complexity. Assume an array of length 4 containing elements a0, a1, a2, a3, create a separate array that contains the sum of i elements for index i.

Original Array arr[]: a0, a1, a2, a3 
Prefix Sum Array p[]: a0, a0+a1, a0+a1+a2, a0+a1+a2+a3

For the sum of 'a1 and a2': a1+a2 = p[2] - p[0]

For the sum of 'a1 and a2 and a3': a1+a2+a3 = p[3] - p[0] 
For the sum of 'a2 and a3': a2+a3 = p[3] - p[1]

The above lines indicate that for the sum of elements from 'L to R' we have to print p[R] - p[L-1]

Note: For L=0, we have to print p[R] because it is the sum of all elements till R, also there is no element with index '-1'.

### Code to create the Prefix sum array:

**If we have an array of containing 'long int' data type and named arr, of size n, then:**

```
long p[n];
p[0] = arr[0];
for(long i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    p[i] = p[i-1] + arr[i];
}
```